# Installed mysql@5.6 using brew mysql.server not a command

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

I installed mysql@5.6 using brew. Below are the comands I ran

```
brew install mysql@5.6

sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/var/mysql

sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/mysql\@5.6/5.6.41/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql

sudo cp /usr/local/Cellar/mysql\@5.6/5.6.41/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist /Library/LaunchAgents/

sudo chown root /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

sudo chmod 600 /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

sudo chmod +x /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

mysql.server start
```

> sh: mysql.server: command not found

this is the output I am getting.
mysql --version is giving output

> mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.41, for osx10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine
>   wrapper

If I start service via brew its starting

```
brew services start mysql@5.6
```

But when I run *mysql -uroot* I am getting

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: There is NO reason for you to execute all those sudo commands.  You are literally breaking your MySQL installation.  Just `brew install mysql@5.6`  then `brew services start mysql@5.6` - that's it.  All the other commands you're doing in between those two steps is ruining everything.

Comment: I am getting the following errror that time too..  ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Jerrys-MacBook-Air.local.pid)

Comment: Can you share the output of: `(f=/usr/local/var/mysql; until [ "$f" = "/" ]; do ls -lda $f; f=$(dirname $f); done)`

Comment: And, the output of: `ls -lda $(/usr/local/bin/mysqld --verbose --help 2>/dev/null | grep -A1 'Default options are read' | tail -1)`

Comment: And, lastly: `ps -ef | grep mysqld`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think you need to start the service as well:

```
brew services start mysql@5.6
```

You can then check so the mysql service is running using:

```
brew services list
```

Now try to create symlinks for the mysql package:

```
brew link --force mysql@5.6
```

You might need to add the location to mysql to your path, to find the location of the package:

```
brew list mysql@5.6
```

Then add the location to the `bin` folder to the end of your `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` file. For instance:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.41/bin
```

Then reload the file:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now you should be able to use the `mysql` and connect to the local running server.

Comment: Error: Formula `mysql` is not installed.

Comment: sorry updated, start should be before the name of the service

Comment: I have tried that, it says  Formula mysql is not installed, maybe because i installed mysql@5.6 ?

Comment: @Jerry - I added some more information that I think will solve your problem.

Comment: . ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Jerrys-MacBook-Air.local.pid).

Comment: @Jerry - If I were you I would start by completely uninstalling the current mysql packages and remove any traces of it: `brew uninstall mysql@5.6` and `rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql /usr/local/etc/my.cnf` and try again

Comment: I did it multiple times :|

Comment: Creating a symlink  fixed mysql command not found on my mojave with mysql@5.7

Answer (score -2):

$ `vi ~/.bash_profile`

write

`PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin`

`PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/support-files`

in it.
save it.

$ `source ~/.bash_profile`
and then try `mysql.server start`

Comment: You should add some explanation to that code. Why should adding something to the `PATH` variable solve a socket problem?

Comment: The problem is not that the command cannot be found, so the above solution would help very little in this case.